# how i can scan ID Card(NIC) in flutter and also get data from it?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, image-scanner

I am building an app in flutter and in that app one step is to scan an id card (NIC) and get their name, DOB, expiry date, etc, so I am confusing that how I can scan and get data. is any package in a flutter, which can help me.

Comment: I don't know what to say in flutter but I know in java it's called TextRecognizer to get text from the camera or any image.

Comment: [blinkid_flutter 5.10.0](https://pub.dev/packages/blinkid_flutter/changelog)

Answer (score 1):

U can use MLKIT to extract data from ID into input field

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This package does exactly what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mrz_scanner

I implemented it today in my flutter app. First it didn't start with this error:

```
Class 'MRZScannerFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
```

But after following [this issue](https://github.com/olexale/flutter_mrz_scanner/issues/18) by replacing this it worked:

In FlutterMrzScannerPlugin.kt

```
class MRZScannerFactory(private val messenger: BinaryMessenger) : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {

override fun create(context: Context?, id: Int, o: Any?): PlatformView {
    return MRZScannerView(context!!, messenger, id)
}
}
```

(`context!!` instead of `context?`)

However, on my phone Xiaomi Mi9T takes very long until it works and the plugin recognizes my German ID, so it's almost unusable. But it's the only free plugin I found for scanning IDs. I'll try it with an iPhone and another ID in the next days, maybe that works better.